# Find the number of generators of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. Find the number of generators of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$, where $r \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 1$

I'm trying to understand the question and am experimenting with $p=5$ and $r=1,2,3$.

When $r=1$ it generates $\mathbb{Z_5}$, where every non-zero element is a generator of the group.

When $r=2$ it generates $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$. All the elements relatively prime to $10$ are $1,3,7,$ and $9$, also $4$ generators.

When $r=3$ it generates $\mathbb{Z_{15}}$. All of the elements relatively prime to $15$ are $1,2,4,7,8,11,13$, and $14$, which are $8$ generators.

So I'm trying to figure out how to find the number of relatively prime elements for the general group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$

Comment: Check out "Euler's phi function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but remember it's $p^r$, not $pr$.  So for instance, for $p=5$ and $r=2$, you get $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$, not $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

This also makes the question easier to answer: you just have to count how many integers between $1$ and $p^r$ are relatively prime to $p^r$.  An integer is relatively prime to $p^r$ iff it is not divisible by $p$ (why?).  To count such integers, you may find it easier to first count the integers between $1$ and $p^r$ that *are* divisible by $p$.  I'll let you finish from here.

Comment: Okay I think that helps, I was reading the $p^r$ wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use the prime counting function as follows: $$ \pi(p^r)−\pi(1),$$ with $$\pi(x) ∼ \frac{x}{\log(x)},$$ so that the number of generators for the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$ is given by $$z(p^r)=\pi(p^r)−\pi(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Whe have $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r} = \{0,1,2,\,\dots,\;p^{r}-1\}$ with $p^r$ elements.

We want elements $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^r}: \gcd(n,p^r)=1.$

> Example of why $\gcd = 1:\;  p=2 \text{ and } r=3.$
> So $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ if $n=2$,
> and $\gcd(2,8)= 2\;\;\Rightarrow\;\; \langle 2\rangle \neq \mathbb{Z}_{2^3}.$
> If $n=3,\; \gcd(3,8) = 1 \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; \langle 3\rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{2^3}.$

But $p^r$ has $p^{r-1}$ divisors, and therefore we have $p^r - p^{r-1}$ generators in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}.\;\;\blacksquare$

Answer (score -2):

I think the formula to calculate the answer of above question is $p^r-p^{r-1}.$
Please re-check it and if there is counter example then notify me.

Comment: Please format your post with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).Also, this formula is hinted at by the currently accepted answer. If you added more details, such as how you derived this, then it may be helpful.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you can give details regarding how you arrived at your formula. As it stands, this answer should be a comment.

Comment: Actually I do not know how to prove this because I derived this formula using patterns i.e. by doing trial and error till p=5.